# Increasing the width of button by a few percent on hover

Tags: html, css, button, hover

So, I have this made.

HTML

```
<div id="navholder" class="bgd">
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Почетна</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Делатност</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Историјат</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Службе</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Колектив</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Контакт</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>

#navholder {
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
    }

#nav {
height: 30px;
margin-top: 10px;
background: #B8860B;
    }

#nav ul li{
margin-top: 3px;
display: inline;
font-size: 120%;
opacity: 1.0;
    }

#nav ul li a {
display: inline-block;
height: 120%;
padding: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 22px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    -1px 0px 22px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
box-shadow:         -1px 0px 22px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
border: 1px solid white;    
opacity: 1.0;
background: #DAA520;

    }

#nav a:hover {
color: white;
background: black;
width: ?
    }
```

I want the buttons once hovered over with a mouse to increase about `20%`. The problem that I found is if I use the exact width like "`width: 60px` not every button is of the same size.

On the other hand if I use `width: 120%` I believe the page takes the width of the whole `#navholder` element which is defined by the class `.bgd`.

Any ideas on how can I make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`transform: scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/GhjsP/)

```
#nav a:hover {
    transform:scale(1.3,1.3);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3,1.3);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.3,1.3);
}
```

Comment: +1! This is definitely the cleanest solution to this specific problem, since it is independent of the sizing method and element context.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you very much for your help JoshC. Also thanks to the other guys who have answered.

Comment: FYI, browser support is limited to IE9+ and requires `-ms-transform` property. http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Answer (score 2):

Just increase the padding on hover:

```
#nav a:hover {
   color: white;
   background: black;
   padding: 5px 10px; /* 5px top/bottom, 10px left/right */
}
```

Comment: True, although the `scale()` transformation could be replicated more accurately using padding on all four sides, a `position: relative;` with a negative `top` and `left` offset, and a `font-size: 1.3em;`, but most browsers these days understand CSS3 transforms.

Answer (score -2):

You may set width with em's and increase font-size.

Also, you may add border/padding on hover:

```
#nav a:hover {
    border-right: solid 20px black;
    /* or padding-right */
}
```